# putting mysql result from php into json object via ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, joomla

Currently I have a helper.php file where I'm getting a mysql result and returning the json_encode version of it:

helper.php file

```
public static function getStoresByZipAjax(){

    $input = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $zip  = $input->get("zip");

    return self::getStores();
}

public static function getStores()
{
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $user = JFactory::getUser();
    
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $lang = JFactory::getLanguage();
    $date = JFactory::getDate();
    $now = $date->format('Y-m-d');
    
    
    $query = 'SELECT name, phone, address, city, state, zip, country, url, logo, lat, lng
                from #__j16cp_store 
                where published = 1; 
    ';
    
    
    $db->setQuery($query);

    $item=$db->loadObjectList();
    $stores = [
        'type' => 'FeatureCollection',
        'features' => array_map(function($i) {
            return [
                'type' => 'Feature',
                'geometry' => [
                    'type' => 'Point',
                    'coordinates' => [
                        $i->lat,
                        $i->lng
                    ]
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    'storeImage' => $i->logo,
                    'storeName' => $i->name,
                    'phoneFormatted' => $i->phone,
                    'address' => $i->address,
                    'city' => $i->city,
                    'country' => $i->country,
                    'postalCode' => $i->zip,
                    'state' => $i->state
                ]
            ];
        }, $item)
    ];
                    
    return json_encode($stores);
}
```

I've been echoing that return in my default.php file into a JS object which has been working fine:

```
const stores = <?php echo $test; ?>
```

however, now I'm grabbing the same result as an ajax response and it's not setting the constant, because I think the structure of the json response is a bit different from the json_encode I was using to test. This is how I'm getting it via ajax:

```
function getApi(bdcApi) {
              Http.open("GET", bdcApi);
              Http.send();
              Http.onreadystatechange = function () {
                  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                    var zip = data.postcode;
                    result.value = zip

                    jQuery.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: "<?php echo JURI::base() . "index.php?option=com_ajax&module=hunter_maps_dev&method=getStoresByZip&zip="?>"  +zip+ "&format=json",
                        success:function(data){
                            console.log('success');

                            const stores = data;

                            console.log(stores);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                          alert(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });  
                  }
              };
```

The data portion of that response looks like this:   `"{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[\"-104.9981929\",`

How can I get this into the same format as how I was echoing the json_encode version but via my ajax response?

I need to get it in this format:

```
 const stores = {
     'type': 'FeatureCollection',
     'features': [
       {
         'type': 'Feature',
         'geometry': {
           'type': 'Point',
           'coordinates': [-77.034084142948, 38.909671288923]
         },
         'properties': {
           'storeImage' : 'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
           'storeName' : 'Test Store',
           'phoneFormatted': '(202) 234-7777',
           'phone': '2022347336',
           'address': '1471 P St NW',
           'city': 'Washington   DC',
           'country': 'United States',
           'crossStreet': 'at 15th St NW',
           'postalCode': '20005',
           'state': 'D.C.'
         }
       },
     ]
   };
```

Comment: Can you elaborate the exact problem? Is the `console.log(stores)` called? If so: has `stores` no value or wrong value?

Comment: It has the right value, ```{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[\"-104.9981929\",``` this is what shows as the data portion of the console.log. But it's not loading in the right format. I've updated the question with the format I'm trying to achieve

Comment: If that's the raw output you're seeing in the browser console it looks like maybe it's been double-encoded somehow. Not obvious how though, from the code you've shown.

Comment: @ADyson well I'm running json_encode on the result in my helper and then the joomla com_ajax is returning the data in the response

Comment: How does the data actually get output from the PHP though? You've shown a function which returns some JSON, but haven't shown how that makes its way into the output of the script

Comment: @ADyson sorry, I updated my answer with the ajax function in my helper.php file

Comment: You can specify the `dataType: 'json'` in the [jquery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). As the `success` data is "[formatted according to the dataType parameter](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#:~:text=formatted%20according%20to%20the%20dataType%20parameter)".

Comment: Ok. But how does `getStoresByZipAjax()` get called? None of this PHP code actually outputs anything into the response. Something else must be calling that function as well. The $.ajax actually makes a request to index.php, so presumably the process starts in that file.

Comment: @ADyson it's' being called in the URL of my ajax code, the com_joomla component requires the method to have Ajax appended to it so the url only callse the method by ```getStoresByZip``` and then the component looks for the ```Ajax``` at the end

Comment: Ah ok so it's a CMS. I don't know Joomla specifically but I would guess since you specified `format=json` in the URL, this would be a signal to the server to encode whatever content is supplied to the output function as JSON. Therefore, it's taking the JSON you give it and encoding it to JSON a second time -  bad! Try putting just `return $stores;` in your `getStores()` function and see what you get. (As a general rule, you shouldn't encode anything to an output format until the actual moment you output it, anyway. While it's within the program it should stay as an object you can work with.)

Comment: Thank you, that actually got me a bit further. I may start a new question because it looks like the issue is that it's not setting a variable and affecting the dom. Thanks!

Comment: You're not telling it to affect the DOM, so it won't. All you're doing is logging it to the console.

Comment: Related: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/31563/12352